# FireBase Security Rules not working with auth.uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I`m trying to set a Firebase rule that will grant access to R/W, if the $uid is equal to auth.uid.
I signed in with firebase phone auth.

Here is auth section of my project:
[image]

And this is my database structure:
[image]

I'am trying this rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

and this rule :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I get an error (Permission Denied), when I try to access the data.

```
    AppController.getInstance().userid = String.valueOf(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
               Log.d("PhoneAuthuid2",AppController.getInstance().userid);
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://xxxdatabase.firebaseio.com/users/");
                   ref.child(AppController.getInstance().userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                           if (snapshot.exists()) {
                               final User userbilgi = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(activation.this, anamenu.class);
                                   intent.putExtra("useruid", userbilgi.getUseruid());
                                   intent.putExtra("phonenumber",userbilgi.getPhonenumber());
                                   intent.putExtra("userdurum", userbilgi.getUserdurum());
                                   intent.putExtra("now", userbilgi.getNow());
                                   intent.putExtra("lastclicktime", userbilgi.getLastclicktime());
                                   intent.putExtra("clickcount", userbilgi.getClickcount());
                                   intent.putExtra("totalclickcount", userbilgi.getTotalclickcount());
                                   intent.putExtra("coincount", userbilgi.getCoincount());
                                   intent.putExtra("satlink",getIntent().getStringExtra("satlink"));
                                   intent.putExtra("reklink",getIntent().getStringExtra("reklink"));
                                   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                           }
                       }
    
                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        Log.d("PhoneAuthFirebase",String.valueOf(firebaseError));
                       }
    
                   });
```

I`m following the Firebase instructions and this rules pass the simulator.

I`m not getting the instance with snapshot from Firebase when these rules are in place.

I would be very grateful if you help to solve the problem.

UPDATE :
Here is simulator result :
[image]
<sub>(source: [imgyukle.com](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/08/22/oCwI9s.png))</sub>

I am trying simulator grant access to read or write. But not in real device. I cant get data from firebase.

Comment: Images for **auth section** and **database structure** attached is not working

Comment: @xaif Here is my code. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Hcsdqcp2fv/

Answer (score 0):

I think it was because of the version mismatch or different packages used for it so it can't can the `auth.uid` in firebase rules